# Error when loading native library in scala

Tags: c++, scala, java-native-interface

I build my C++ to a `hello.dll` library to use it in scala.

When I load it with `System.loadLibrary("hello")`, then appear the exception:

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\ducnm4\Desktop\mdb_scala\hello.dll: Can't find dependent libraries.`

The path point to the `hello.dll` is right so I don't know why it's happen ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have another DLL which your DLL depends upon, and which is not found in PATH.

Often this other DLL is the MSVC runtime (named something like msvcr*.dll). Use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) to figure out exactly which dependencies are missing. Find them and copy them to the folder where your Dll lives.

Comment: I don't think so, I am trying to understand JNI and find some tutorials about it that the dll contain only a fucntion say hello so what can it missing ? the web I refered to say nothing about that

Comment: If you don't want to use Dependency Walker, fine, continue to search the web. Hope it will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: msvcrtxxx.dll is the microsoft c++ runtime. All c++ dlls depend on it. However, if it is on the same machine as where you built the dll, it should definitely be on the system.

Comment: I did use DW and find out that I miss the cygwin1.dll
thanks in advance :D
now it turn to a new error when I run it, I cannot get access to the cygwin1.dll file throw error EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Comment: This is a different problem for a different question. Use a debugger.